# Adding numbers from a list python (packed)

Tags: python, list

Well I have several lists in python which are related to the hours of the year. What I want to do is make packages of 24 hours and sum the numbers of these lists accordingly.

Moreover, I do not know if working with lists is the proper way or better with dictionaries.

```
h = [1,2,3,4,...]
x = [22.5,0,58,35,...]
```

So from `x`I want to add up the numbers in blocks of 24, which are the hours per day.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

especially provide input, desired output and your attempt at coding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
x = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(576)] #populate list
print [sum(x[i:i+24]) for i in range(0, len(x), 24)] #[1235, 1340, 1000, 1114, 1121, 1479, 1355, 1063, 1093, 1259, 1191, 1299, 1018, 1518, 1326, 1155, 1400, 1404, 1239, 1062, 1015, 1306, 1086, 1178]
```